# Rounding a number up to get no decimal

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script (in J Script) that takes the pressure of Oil in a pump, and displays it on a digital display.

The problem is that the Pump outputs the pressure level in Pascals, while the digital display is intended to display in PSI (the number of digits on the display is limited to 4, and the pressure levels of the oil in the pump in pascals is like 15 digits.)

Currently the script is simple :

```
var Pump1_Digi : Demo3D.Visuals.BoxVisual = sender.FindChild("Pump1_Oil_Pressure_Digi");

Pump1_Digi.Pressure_Num = sender.Pump1_Oil_Pressure;
Pump1_Digi.PropertiesUpdated;
```

Pump1_Digi.Pressure_Num is the value I write to that is displayed on the digital display.

sender.Pump1_Oil_Pressure is the acutal value of the oil pressure **in pascals.**

I know that 6894.757 Pascals is 1 PSI

so I can do this:

```
var Pump1_Digi : Demo3D.Visuals.BoxVisual = sender.FindChild("Pump1_Oil_Pressure_Digi");
var Pump1toPSI : Pressure;

sender.Pump1_Oil_Pressure / 6894.757 = Pump1toPSI;

Pump1_Digi.Pressure_Num = Pump1toPSI
Pump1_Digi.PropertiesUpdated;
```

While my result is now in PSI, the numbers after the decimal point go on nearly for ever.

What I would like to do is just round the result to the nearest whole number.

Is there a parse function in Jscript to accomplish this? Or does anyone know of a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want the `Math.ceil()` function to round up to the nearest integer. Or `Math.round()` to round up or down as necessary:

```
Math.ceil(1.2098344305985700003482);
// 2

Math.round(1.2098344305985700003482);
// 1
```

Comment: Link to reference for [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) at the Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: that rounds only up... 0.00001 is 1 with this method.  If you want to use the math object you could use `Math.round()`

Comment: @Joseph I thought I read the question as specifically asking to round up, but I see I misread.